# Application is repeatedly opened

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm developing an application. When i exit from the application, it will be opened again (The first activity is called again and again). So i couldn't able to exit from it.

In some other activities I use EXIT button and proper code to exit. Even when I click the EXIT button on those activities, it will start login activity. (login page is opened)

In my application, I use

1) Main

2) ScreenActivity

3) Login

flow: (from main->screenActivity->login)

The start page (1st activity) is posted below

```
public class main extends Activity {
static ConnectivityManager conMgr;

BackgroundThread backgroundThread;
TextView myText;
boolean myTextOn = true;
Cursor cursor;
String response="";
public SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

private  SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

public class BackgroundThread extends Thread {

boolean running = false;



 void setRunning(boolean b){
 running = b;
}

@Override
 public void run() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //super.run();
 while(running){
  try {
  sleep(1000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
 }
catch(Exception e)
{

}
handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
}
}

}

Handler handler = new Handler(){

 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //super.handleMessage(msg);
 if (myTextOn){
  myTextOn = false;
  myText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
 else{
  myTextOn = true;
  myText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
}

};



  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.thread);

   myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);




}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStart();
if(isInternetAvailable())
{
 Toast.makeText(this, "online", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

startActivity(new Intent(main.this, ScreenActivity.class));
}
else{

    startActivity(new Intent(main.this, splashscreen.class));

    Toast.makeText(this, "offline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


 backgroundThread = new BackgroundThread();
 backgroundThread.setRunning(true);
   backgroundThread.start();

}



private boolean isInternetAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
return true;
}
return false;

}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStop();

boolean retry = true;
backgroundThread.setRunning(false);

 while(retry){
 try {
 backgroundThread.join();
 retry = false;
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}

}



}

public void onDEstroy()
{
super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

ScreenActivity:

```
public class ScreenActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
private TextView animatedView3; 
//ImageView image;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash); 



   /* Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  
            R.anim.anima);  
    animation1.setAnimationListener(this);  
    View animatedView1 = findViewById(R.id.aet1);  
    animatedView1.startAnimation(animation1);  


    /** set time to splash out */


    final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 9000;
    /** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
    Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

        int wait = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                super.run();
                /**
                 * use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
                 * the wait variable for every 100L.
                 */
                while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                    sleep(100);
                    wait += 100;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
            } finally {
                /**
                 * Called after splash times up. Do some action after splash
                 * times up. Here we moved to another main activity class
                 */
                startActivity(new Intent(ScreenActivity.this,
                        login.class));

            }
        }
    };
    welcomeThread.start();

}

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {  

}  

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {  
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Animation ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    if (animatedView3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {  
        animatedView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
    } else {  
        animatedView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
    }  
}  

public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {  
   // Toast.makeText(this, "Animation rep", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

}  
}
```

Please can anyone explain about the problem and how to solve it? I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `finish()` in your `loginActivity` and for other `Activities` as well else stack will store the list of visited `Activities`.

Comment: How it will solve my problem? What is the problem on the code

Comment: The problem in your code is you have to call finish() while moving from first activity to second and so on.... If you didnt called finish() then the last visited activity will be in the stack. So place finish() in the activity before moving to another one...

Comment: where you have placed finish()? Place after startActivity() in if(!isInternetAvaiable())and else part as well...

Comment: I've placed it before startActivity(). (in Previous line)

Comment: Ok.. I'm trying now with after startActivity()

Comment: launchmode is needed or not

Comment: I didn't use launch mode only finish the activity